# How do I specify color in RGB using \hypersetup in hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, color

How do I specify color in RGB using `\hypersetup` in `hyperref`?

I know that this is the right way to do it with color names:

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            urlcolor=Maroon,
            linkcolor=Maroon}
```

But I want `Teal`, which `hyperref` doesn't recognize. I know `Teal = {0 128 128}` in RGB, but the following code won't compile:

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            urlcolor={0 128 128},
            linkcolor={0 128 128}}
```

I have tried it with comma separators, proportional values (e.g. `0 < x < 1`), but to no avail. What is the right way to do it? Also mention the correct `texdoc` that I should read for further info.

Comment: To specify colors as RGB byte triplets as in your example, replace `rbg` with `RGB` in [Geoffrey Jones answer below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4506/13043). E.g. `urlcolor = [RGB]{0 128 128}`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you'd really prefer to specify RGB colours in `\hypersetup` without loading the `(x)color` package, you can always type them in directly like this:

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            urlcolor=[RGB]{0,0.5,0.5},
            linkcolor=[RGB]{0,0.5,0.5}}
```

Still, as Ulrike mentioned, loading `xcolor` is usually the more comfortable way to go.  Although probably a little overkill for your problem, this is how I generally proceed:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor}
```

Note that you can specify multiple colour name spaces so long as you're not too concerned about name clashes (otherwise read the rules about this in the `xcolor` manual).  Since you're loading `xcolor` to fit in with `hyperref`, don't forget to include the `[hyperref]` option as you go.

Comment: I wonder why there is no mention of the `[rgb]` option in `texdoc hyperref`? Do you happen to know where it is documented?

Comment: @Kit, like many things in TeX/LaTeX, the ultimate documentation is the source code itself. I just stuck my nose into `hyperref.sty` (and child packages that it loads) to figure out how it does things. Classic case of "no pain, no gain", wot? `:)`

Comment: More like slowly but surely for me `:)` And also, the sooner I accept that source code is the best documentation, the better. And to be able to read source code, I'll need the TeXbook, right?

Answer (score 13):

You must define the name of color first. In the case of Teal it is not necessary as it is defines in `svgnam.def`, so you can use the `svgnames` option.

```
 \documentclass{book}
 \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
 %\definecolor{Teal}{RGB}{0,128,128}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
             urlcolor=Teal,
             linkcolor=Teal}
 \begin{document}
 \url{abc}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I got `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` error for `...{0 128 128}` and had to change it to `{0,128,128}`. Not sure if space separated form is wrong, so not editing the answer.

Comment: @xaizek: I don't get an error with my code (with the color definition activated), imho both syntax (with space and with commas) should work, but commas are the official one, so I edited the code.