# How can I make internal links both colored and underlined?

Tags: hyperref, color, links, text-decorations

I would like the internal hyperlinks generated by [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to be colored **and** underlined.

Reading some of the package documentation, I know that these `\hypersetup` keys exist:

- `colorlinks`: when `true`, color the link; when `false`, draw a border around the link and color that.
- `linkcolor`: the color of the link (requires `colorlinks=true` to have any effect)
- `linkbordercolor`: the color of the link border color (requires `colorlinks=false` to have any effect)
- `pdfborderstyle`: keys for the pdf borderstyle dictionary.  I don't know what keys and values exist for this dictionary, but I do know that `pdfborderstyle={/S/U}` or `pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}` can change the link border from a box to an underline.

But it seems impossible with this key structure to have colored links (requiring `colorlinks=true`) and colored borders (requiring `colorlinks=false`).

Here is a minimal (non-)working example ([via](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2011-01/msg00323.html)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,%
            linkbordercolor=red,linkcolor=green,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}

\begin{document}
\section{To See}\label{tosee}
\vskip2cm
\hyperref[tosee]{just to see}
\end{document}
```

With `colorlinks=false` (the default) the text is black and the border is red.

With `colorlinks=true` the text is green and there is no border.

Comment: Color hyperlinks has been discussed, just recently, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/how-do-i-specify-color-in-rgb-using-hypersetup-in-hyperref)

Comment: Related Question: [Switch between box and color links with hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120610/switch-between-box-and-color-links-with-hyperref/).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I assume this was done by design, seeing as the introduction of hyperlinks may clutter the user's view of the actual text. Moreover, not all hyperlink typesetting is printable - as you've mentioned, the PDF hyperlink is merely "a rectangular area of the page that is mouse-aware". However, if you want to do this, there are two options available

---

## Manual

You *deactivate* the `colorlinks` option so that `hyperref` sets the link border:

```
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=false,% hyperlinks will be black
  linkbordercolor=red,% hyperlink borders will be red
  pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}% border style will be underline of width 1pt
}
```

and typeset the text manually using `\color{<color>}`. For example:

```
...
\begin{document}
  \section{To See}\label{tosee}
  \hyperref[tosee]{\color{green}just to see}
\end{document}
```

[image: Colorlinks=false with manual colour setting of link]

Note that this is virtually the same as what `hyperref` does internally, since the text colour is modified and will typeset this way even if the hyperlink is removed via printing to PDF (or flattening).

The advantage behind this approach (motivating to include it here) is that you can specify different colours for each hyperlink, if you so wish.

---

## Automatic

You *activate* the `colorlinks` option so that `hyperref` sets the link colour in the text

```
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,% hyperlinks will be coloured
  linkcolor=green,% hyperlink text will be green
  linkbordercolor=red,% hyperlink border will be red
}
```

and then add the following after the above `\hypersetup{...}`:

```
\makeatletter
\Hy@AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\@pdfborder{0 0 1}% Overrides border definition set with colorlinks=true
  \def\@pdfborderstyle{/S/U/W 1}% Overrides border style set with colorlinks=true
                                % Hyperlink border style will be underline of width 1pt
}
\makeatother
```

[image: Colorlinks=true with linkborder active]

---

Here is the [`pdfborderstyle` specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf) from **Adobe**:

[image: PDF border specification]

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to patch `hyperref` so that the links use `soul`'s `\ul` and no border-underlining?

Comment: Curiously, the pdfborderstyle specifications have effect only if the file is opened by Adobe Reader. They do not work e.g. with Apple's Preview.

Comment: @Werner As Jairo Bochi said, this does not work for macOS preview, is there a way for it to work in preview? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to raise the underline up a bit higher? It's so low that it bumps against the next line of text

Comment: Doesn't work: Undefined control sequence. \hypersetup

Comment: @Conjecture: Care to share a minimal document that replicates your issue?

Comment: How do you change the color of the underline?

Comment: @Adam_G: `linkbordercolor=blue`

Answer (score 20):

I know you're probably looking for a solution that uses `hyperref`'s own underlining just for the heck of it, but I'm adding this answer just in case anybody ever actually wants to use colored and underlined links (against which I advise). `hyperref`'s underlining isn't particularly pretty, in fact, it's just the bottom line of a box. `soul`'s underlining is prettier and much more customizable (see its [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf#page=12)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul,lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\myhy}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{\color{green}\setulcolor{red}\ul{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\section{To See}\label{tosee}
\vskip2cm
This is \myhy{tosee}{just to see} what it looks like. \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: underlining with soul]

Here's the `hyperref` underlining, as a comparison:

[image: underlining with hyperref]

Comment: @Matthew: Aah, I hadn't even thought of the automatically generated links. In this case, we'd probably need to patch some of `hyperref.sty`. I had taken a quick peek into it, but I didn't understand a word.

Comment: This worked for me to get underlined *clickable* links: `\newcommand{\myhy}[2]{\href{#1}{\color{blue}\setulcolor{blue}\ul{#2}}}`
`

Answer (score 2):

If you only need it a couple times you don't need a new command or any extra packages. Just add underline and color to the link label:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\href{https://www.example.com}{[{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{link}}}]}
```

Comment: This, like the other answer by k-dubs prevents longer links from wrapping. But still, thanks for your answer.

Comment: -1 The question is about styling the **internal** hyperlinks generated by `hyperref` **automatically**. This answer shows how to style _external_ hyperlinks _manually_.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang well then by all means downvote it so that it won't even be visible to the people who would've found it helpful because if it wasn't exactly what YOU needed

Comment: Nothing personal, just pointing out that the answer is orthogonal to the question. This is a Q&A site, not a wiki. If you want to write an answer about something else (perhaps for the benefit of googlers who landed here in search of something else), go ahead, but the answer should say that it's addressing a related-but-different question. Then I'll retract the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that does not require a new package, nor overriding `hyperref` parameters is to define a new command, e.g., `slink`:

```
\documentclass{article}

%minimum packages
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} 

%custom link command
\newcommand{\slink}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{\underline{\smash{#2}}}} 

\begin{document}
    \section{Section Title\label{sect}}
    \slink{sect}{Here} is an \texttt{slink} to this very section 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will prevent longer links from wrapping around line ends.

Comment: This is very similar to doncherry's answer, and my comments on that answer apply here.   I wanted to style *automatically generated* hyperlinks.  They all use `\hyperref` alone.  A new user command wrapping around `\hyperref` doesn't address this use case.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Ah, I didn't understand those comments, my mistake. Although, this addressed *my* use case and perhaps those of others who find this thread. Trying to figure out how to color *and* underline links with `hyperref` was how I found this thread: "How can I have colored and underlined links with hyperref?". This is a (possibly inelegant) way to do that.

Comment: @AlexG: I noticed that. Do you know how to avoid it?

Comment: Well, @Werner 's solution (under the heading "**Automatic**") does exactly what was requested: `\hypersetup{...}` configures the link text to be coloured while keeping it line-breakable and  the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` patches `hyperref` to implement the PDF specification for setting the link border style to "Underline". That's all what is needed to fulfill the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions up to this point have worked in my case. What I tried to resolve? Display *all* external links (URLs) colored `black` and underlined with 1px line (resume). There's a single requirement, no custom styles for `href` needed.

The original answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26085/125035) has almost everything what I need except one small thing. It does not work with actual URLs leading to external web resources, e.g. link on a twitter account.

Be careful and double check what *exactly* you want to color & underline. The official [hyperref documentation](https://mirrors.up.pt/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html) helps me a lot to figure out. In example, check out section '5.6 Extension options' and read more about the difference between `linkcolor`, `urlcolor` and other *color parameters.

I also found [the solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414091/125035) in another question. You can use the code from the answer, it works just okay. IMO the `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/S/W 1}}}` thing is kind of workaround in my simple case. My solution is:

```latex
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    urlbordercolor = black,
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1},
}
```

As a result, `\href{mailto:email@gmail.com}{email@gmail.com}` external URL displays the right way.

[image: .pdf resume example]