# Arxiv.org: remove borders around hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, arxiv, obsolete

The answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks) already explain how to remove the borders around hyperlinks.

However, if I submit a manuscript to [Arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/), it seems that their system somehow manages to override the `\hypersetup` command. The end result is ugly: bright green, red, and cyan boxes all around the PDF file. However, it does not just *ignore* all `\hypersetup` commands; for example, `\hypersetup{pdfauthor=...}` works as expected.

Does anyone happen to know any workarounds?

AFAIK, Arxiv.org uses a system that is based on Texlive 2009 and [TeX::AutoTeX](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TeX-AutoTeX/). I am defining `\pdfoutput=1`, i.e., the document is compiled using `pdflatex`.

Comment: @lockstep: Why the [tag:obsolete] tag?

Comment: @Caramdir: In his answer, Jukka pointed out that a "too old" version of `hyperref` was the problem.

Comment: @lockstep: I'd see Jukka's second answer (hyperref.cfg changes) as the actual problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With a lot of trial and error, I finally found a solution. This works:

```
\pdfoutput=1
...
\usepackage{hyperref}
...
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
}
```

The links are invisible, there are no borders or colours. Trickery with `00README.XXX` does not seem to be necessary.

---

**Some remarks…**

Any approach based on `pdfborder={0 0 0}` seems to fail. Options `hidelinks` and `allcolors` are not supported; the hyperref version that Arxiv.org uses is too old.

I realised that I have to *enable* `colorlinks` only after reading [Ryan Reich's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30243/arxiv-org-remove-borders-around-hyperlinks/30259#30259), in which he mentions that the colorlinks option and customised link colours seem to work fine.

I still do not understand exactly what is going on here—how is it possible that `colorlinks` disables borders while `pdfborder` does not work? Anyway, I guess I will just blindly copy-and-paste this fragment of code in future and forget about it. :)

---

**Update 2022**

Using the original `\hypersetup` from this answer, a recent upload to arXiv still compiled with bright-coloured rectangles around links. The following `\hypersetup` managed to get the job done:

```
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0},
}
```

- `pdfborderstyle` adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26085/62114)
- note that `pdfborder` is probably redundant and ignored by
  arXiv

Comment: Is this still working for anyone? I tried uploading a manuscript with all `\pdfoutput=1 ... \usepackage{hyperref} ... \begin{document} ... \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, urlcolor=black,}` but it still ended up with those brightly coloured boxes around references

Answer (score 3):

I was sure that the arXiv FAQ had an answer to this, but all it has is [this](http://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#nohypertex), which tells you how to *disable* automatic hyperref.  I don't do this, but it will certainly work if you simply create at `00README.XXX` file, say `nohypertex` in it, and just roll your own hyperlinks (it won't ignore anything you write in the document; this will just disable its own attempts at hyperlinking).  I remember I did this in the first version of my first paper.

In any case, my own papers seem to have no special provisions: I have `\pdfoutput=1` at the top, and then `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}` later.  I also have a `\hypersetup` changing some link colors, which is obeyed.

Do you put `colorlinks` in the `\usepackage` or the `\hypersetup`?  Try doing the former.  The hyperref manual suggests that some options have "restricted" use, so this may make a difference.

Finally, it's possible that the arXiv scripts are to blame here: perhaps they detect the loading of `\hyperref` and modify their own use of it accordingly.

**Edit:** Although you seem to have gotten some use from what I wrote, it does indeed look like the arXiv is ignoring the `pdfborder = {0 0 0}` directive.  One workaround that I tested myself is to use the alternative command `linkbordercolor = {1 1 1}` (i.e. white), which is not ignored.  I don't know what was going on with the other option, unfortunately.  `00README.XXX` is not required.

Comment: `00README.XXX` with `nohypertex` does not help. It does not matter if I put `pdfborder={0 0 0}` in `\usepackage` or `\hypersetup`; in both cases it is ignored, even if I use `nohypertex`.

Comment: @Jukka: Suppose you just try to remove all hyperlinks entirely.  Does `00README.XXX` work for that (i.e. does it work as intended at all)?  Perhaps you could test this with a fake MWE submission for easier debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I received the following answer by email from Thorsten Schwander; I am quoting it here with his permission (with some formatting):

> arXiv sets \pdfborderstyle in its hyperref.cfg
>
> depending on where your \hypersetup is placed and what options you
>   set, this may take preference.
>
> the current settings in arXiv's
>   /texlive/2009/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg:
>
> ```
> \hypersetup{
>  linktocpage=true,
>  pdfborderstyle={/S/S/W 1},
>  hyperindex=true,
>  bookmarks=true,
>  bookmarksopen=true,
>  bookmarksnumbered=true,
> }
> ```