# How to set up spell-checking with vim?

Tags: vim, spelling

I'm using `vim` to write my thesis. It's a multi-document project, with most tex files in subdirectories from the master-document. I've set up a couple of `\newcommands` to replace the use of `\section*{}` in the Introduction, but when writing the sections, misspelt words aren't highlighted.

I thought it was a problem with `vim-latexsuite`, so I've just uninstalled it, but still, spell-checking functionality doesn't work in these sections.

For example, a MWE with the following files:-

```
thesis.tex
thesis.tex.latexmain
Classes/Thesis.cls
Intro/intro.tex
```

thesis.tex :

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany,titlepage,12pt]{Classes/Thesis}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}

\include{Intro/intro}

% ...

\end{document}
```

Classes/Thesis.cls :

```
\ProvidesClass{Classes/Thesis}[2014/07/14 v1.2 Thesis template]

\LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex,
            plainpages = false,
            pdfpagelabels,
            bookmarks,
            bookmarksopen = true,
            bookmarksnumbered = true,
            breaklinks = true,
            linktocpage,
            pagebackref,
            colorlinks = true,
            % Colour settings from::
            % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30243
            linkcolor=NavyBlue,
            citecolor=BrickRed,
            filecolor=black,
            urlcolor=BrickRed,
            hyperindex = true,
            hyperfigures
            ]{hyperref}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\newcommand\chapwtoc[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \chapter*{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \markboth{#1}{}
}

\newcommand\secwtoc[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \section*{#1}%
  \markright{#1} % Get the Section name in headnotes
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
}
```

Intro/intro.tex :

```
\chapwtoc{First chapter}

this is a msisisspelt word. Some mnore mis-spellings.


\secwtoc{First section}

some more misskjkpellings.

% vim: spell spelllang=en_gb
```

`thesis.tex.latexmain` is an empty file, as suggested in the latexsuite documentation for [Multiple file LaTeX projects](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project.html)

How do I get spell-checking to work in the `intro.tex` sections? Using vim 7.4 on Linux

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a colour scheme issue? With the default colour scheme “this” and “some” are highlighted, not so “chapwtoc” and “missdklkjpllings”. When I change the colour scheme to e.g. `desert` then all misspellings are highlighted.

Comment: I'm just using the default colorscheme, but no difference with `desert`, or others...

Comment: The only highlighted words in `intro.tex` are in the vim settings line: `spelllang` and `gb`. If I use `\chapter*` and `\section*`, then it works as expected..

Comment: As yours worked, I had a look in my `~/.vimrc`, and I found the culprit: `let g:tex_flavor = "latex"`. Removing that fixes it

Comment: oww, well that fixed it for the MWE, but not my actual thesis intro.

Comment: Then start with a minimal working `.vimrc` and add your custom configuration line by line (or do a bisect). Then you'll find the offending line or setting.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with my `.vimrc` now, but the content of my actual `introduction.tex`. I just copied it over to the MWE - it doesn't work - so i'm cutting stuff out of it to see if I can the problem...

Comment: Seems to be a filetype detection problem.. I opened the two intro's side-by-side and noticed that the commands were highlighted in different colours. Where spell-checking doesn't work, `set filetype` returns `tex`, whereas when it does work, it detects `plaintex`.. Guess I'll have to add the filetype to the settings line..

Comment: Indeed, seems to be a bug in `tex` documents, as opposed to `plaintex` docs. In the MWE, `set filetype=tex` breaks spell-checking. In my actual thesis, `set filetype=plaintex` fixes it.

Answer (score 9):

You can force spell checking for tex documents by putting the following into *.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim* or *.vim/after/ftplugin/tex/spelling.vim*:

```
set spelllang=en_gb spell
```

Your approach to do it with modeline magic

```
% vim: spell spelllang=en_gb
```

should work too, but you need to explicitly enable modelines. (They can be a security issue.) To do so, put the following into your *.vimrc*:

```
set modeline
```

Comment: Both solutions doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I'm still getting spelling errors in `\href{}{}`.

Comment: That has nothing to do with this question @RaffiKhatchadourian. Please open a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Enable file type plugin:

```
echo -e 'filetype plugin on' >> ~/.vimrc
or
echo -e 'filetype plugin indent on' >> ~/.vimrc
```

Enable spell check for tex files and disable syntax:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/ftplugin/
echo -e 'set spell\nsyntax off' >> ~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim
```

To temporarily enable syntax, execute in vim:

```
:syn on
```