# VIM default language for tex files

Tags: languages, vim, spelling

I don't really know if I'm right here, if so please say something.

But, I currently work on my bachelor-thesis and want to enable spell check in my VIM. But currently I have to do this every time when I open up a new document. Is there a way to enable spell checking and choose a default language in my `.vimrc` for all .tex files???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has been asked before. I answered it there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162262/15616

Answer (score 2):

Perfect! Thanks @canaaerus this worked well! https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162262/15616

But for all those who use Pathogen and LaTeX-Box like me, I add the following line

```
set spelllang=en_gb spell
```

into `.vim/bundle/LaTeX-Box/after/syntax/tex.vim`.