# Why are my subscripts with \ref too big? Only happens on arxiv pdf

Tags: subscripts, arxiv

Why are the subscripts on constants too large in the following arxiv paper?

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.00822v1.pdf

This happens only on the arxiv, not when I compile the document at home or at work.

Look for example at Theorem 1.1.  In the sentence "There are positive constants $C_1$" etc. the subscripts are the correct size, but in the inequality at the end of the statement of the theorem the subscripts are too large.

We use the following macros to automatically number constants:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{constant}
\newcommand{\newC}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{constant} C_{\theconstant} \label{C:#1}%
}
\newcommand{\refC}[1]{C_{\ref{C:#1}}}

\begin{document}
New constant: \( \newC{test} \)

Reuse the constant: \( \refC{test} \)
\end{document}
```

The incorrectly-sized subscripts seem to happen whenever we use the \refC macro, but not \newC.  Is this something to do with using \ref in a subscript?

Comment: It looks like arxiv adds hyperlinks to any label reference (in the paper, you can click on the subscripts in the inequality), and the hyperlinks are typeset differently.

Comment: Oh, that will be because I am using the hyperref package.  The subscripts are hyperlinks in the PDF I compiled at home too.

Comment: It seems that arxiv uses a custom hyperref config, you could try to bypass or disable it (see arxiv f.a.q., or [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30243/arxiv-org-remove-borders-around-hyperlinks/30261#30261))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to TonioElGringo for his comments.  It seems that this was due to the hyperref config on arxiv.  I don't need the subscripts to be hyperlinks anyway, so I could avoid this by using \ref* instead of \ref.