# Preview on OS 10.7 does not display links in PDFs correctly

Tags: hyperref, links, mac

I would like links to appear as coloured underlines in my documents. The following short example produces a pdf that displays the link correctly in Acrobat, but not in Preview. In Preview it shows up as a box:

[image]

Is there a way I can get Preview to display the link as an underline using commands in `\hypersetup`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}
}


\begin{document}

\url{www.google.com}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't specific to OS 10.7 (or even the Mac).  Not all PDF viewers support the `pdfborderstyle`.

Comment: Well, that's a pain in the butt.

Comment: With OS 10.7, I need to add `http://` if I want an active link with Preview, Skim or Safari. Safari says : bad character in the link. I try with `\href`instead of `\url` but the problems are the sames with "underline" and "http". Actually, I need to write `\href{http://www.google.com}{www.google.com}`

Comment: @Altermundus `\nolinkurl` can be used to get the link typeset in the same way as `\url` but without the link. Result with complete URL: `\href{http://www.google.com/}{\nolinkurl{www.google.com}}`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't specific to OS 10.7 (or even the Mac). Not all PDF viewers support the `pdfborderstyle`, so if Preview doesn't there's not much that can be done about it.  However, in this question: [How can I have colored and underlined links with hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/2693) there's an answer by [doncherry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4012/doncherry) which implements underlining manually via the `soul` package.  This might be an alternative.