# Hypersetup to underline only cite texts

Tags: hyperref

Is there a way to only *box* my cite or *underline* only my cite?

I dont want to change the font color of my cite or anything. Is there a way to do that with hypersetup? In the image below, I just want the cite text to be underlined or boxed with a color. How to do it?

[image: Gustaffson and Webb]

Comment: What do you mean by 'only'?  Loading `hyperref` without any options like `colorlinks` (and related) will make citations appear in a coloured box --- but so will things like `\ref` and `\pageref` and figures.  Do you want to disable hyperlinking for those last three?

Comment: you could take a look at this post:

[http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/27833][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/27833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/27833) by using

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,linkbordercolor=red,linkcolor=green,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}
```

`linkbordercolor=red,` hyperlink borders will be red

`pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}` border style will be underline of width 1pt