# Switch between box and color links with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, links

How can I have both boxed and color links in the same document?  I know I can use `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}` and have colored links instead of boxes, but how do I have both in the same document.  The MWE below yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- This is intended for use only in the review version of the document where I want to be able to distinguish different types of links.  In the final version there will be a single style.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{www.google.com}{The Google} 

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}
\href{www.google.com}{The Google} 

\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}
\href{www.google.com}{The Google} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Question: [How can I have colored and underlined links with hyperref?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `colorlinks` is activated, then the color can be disabled by using the current color `.` that is provided by package `xcolor`. The setting for `pdfborder` enables or disables the annotation frame:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}, urlcolor=.}%
}

\begin{document}
\href{www.google.com}{The Google}

\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}, urlcolor=blue}
\href{www.google.com}{The Google}

\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}, urlcolor=.}
\href{www.google.com}{The Google}

\textcolor{red}{\href{www.google.com}{The Google}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]