# Why isn't mupdf displaying borders for hyperref links?

Tags: hyperref

I don't know if this is a bug to report to Artifex, maker of **mupdf**, or it's an issue with **hyperref** package.  If it's the latter, is there a workaround?

If I run the following code through pdflatex, I get what's expected when viewing the pdf output with, say, Firefox.  Further down is a screen capture which shows what I'm seeing.  For comparison, I'm also including a screen capture for mupdf.  Boxes are gone. Why?  In my experience, mupdf is extremely good at rendering PDFs.

In hyperref documentation and other posts, I've read something to the effect:  "borders aren't for *printed* output".  Hmmm.  Is that how mupdf is treating them, whereas other programs are rendering the PDF for the screen?  I don't know how the rendering program could be making this distinction.  (By the way, I've tried this with mupdf from version 1.7 to current version 1.21.  No difference.)

The following code is borrowed from [Switch between box and color links with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120610/switch-between-box-and-color-links-with-hyperref/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}, urlcolor=.}%
}

\begin{document}
\href{www.google.com}{The Google}

\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}, urlcolor=blue}
\href{www.google.com}{The Google}

\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}, urlcolor=.}
\href{www.google.com}{The Google}

\textcolor{red}{\href{www.google.com}{The Google}}
\end{document}
```

Firefox rendering:

[image]

mupdf rendering:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a mupdf bug going back many years.  See https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695159