# printing colored borders of hyperref package (latex)

Tags: color, pdf, printing

I Want to print the borders of `hyperref` package in LaTeX. Using the package `\usepackage{hyperref}`, in the pdf file, some borders (red, green, etc) appears. When the document is printed the borders does not appear (which is logical).

Happens that I want to print those borders. Is it possible ?

Comment: Related: [How can I have colored and underlined links with `hyperref`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PDF reader decides whether these borders are shown and/or printed. If you want to make sure these are printed, you can use normal frames instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This is a \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\framebox{link}}.
\end{document}
```

`framebox` creates a (black) frame, the `hidelinks` option to `hyperref` prevents the normal (non-printable) frame from showing up.

---

A macro to replace `\href`:

```
\newcommand{\framedhref}[2]{\href{#1}{\framebox{#2}}}
```

Comment: I have more than 100 hyper references in my document so I'm looking for an automatic solution. Is it possible to change the definition in the pdf reader or use another one to print the borders ?

Comment: I don't know any PDF reader which will print these borders. Add the `hidelinks`, define a command for framed links (see my updated answer), and replace each occurrence of `\href{` with the new macro.

Comment: This will have problems if the linked text happens to be over two lines.  For instance, try adding the following to the MWE: `To get to your favorite site you need to click on the following \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\framebox{link to the \TeX{} Stackexchange site}}.` with the `\usepackage{showframe}` to see.