# Appendix- Elsarticle

Tags: appendices, elsarticle

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

\appendix \label{Appendix}
\section{Mass matrix}\label{Mass Matrix}
Blabla ....

\section{Gyroscopic matrix}\label{Gyroscopic Matrix}
Blabla...

\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image]

Is it possible to have just one appendix without A and B? and How I
 can refer to the appendix in my text ?

Comment: Normally you would refer to *Appendix A*, but if you leave out the numbering ... you would just say *it's in the appendix*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you appear to want to create an unnumbered appendix section, the normal `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism won't do the job. Instead, I suggest you load the `hyperref` package -- you may already be doing so -- and use that package's `\hypertarget`-`\hyperlink` mechanism, as is done in the code below.

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

As will be shown in the \hyperlink{app}{appendix}, \dots

\appendix
\hypertarget{app}{\section*{Appendix. Mass matrix and gyroscopic matrix}}

Blabla \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got the reference in blue color. How Can I put it in black ?

Comment: Hmmm, there seems to be no elegant way to change the link color. Thus, I suggest you use brute force, i.e., write `\hyperlink{app}{\textcolor{black}{appendix}}` instead of `\hyperlink{app}{appendix}`.

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/34551) will tell you how to customize the way links are produced.

Comment: @Clément - My suggestion uses slightly less brute force [!] than some of the suggestions made in the posting you provided a link to. :-)

Comment: @Mico It works for the reference appendix, it becomes black.  But the other references becomes blue, I used this one but always blue: "\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref}"

Comment: @S_25 -- You'll have to use the `\textcolor{black}{...}}` kludge with all `\hyperlink` instances.

Comment: @Mico I used this one as exemple \textcolor{black}{\cite{ML1986}}, but always in blue

Comment: @S_25 - Are you encasing `\cite` instructions in `\hyperlink{...}` wrappers? If so, why?

Comment: I did this \hyperlink{app}{\textcolor{black}{\cite{ML1986}}}  and this \textcolor{black}{\cite{ML1986}} but always in blue

Comment: @S_25 - The question is: *Why* are you employing the wrappers? Why not just `\cite{ML1986}`?

Comment: I did and the reference are in blue

Comment: @S_25 - So, your new questions are apparently only minimally related to the substance of your earlier posting. Please post a *new* query -- preferably in the form of an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001)
 -- in which you detail the new issue(s) you're looking to fix. Many thanks in advance.