# Can you help me with a bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

I have done this, but the webpages don't appear.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}\\

\bibitem{work1}...\\
\bibitem{work9}J O'Connor i E F Robertson: Squaring the circle [en línia] <\underline{http:www-gap.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/HistTopics/Squaring_the_circle.html}>.\\

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Load package `url` or `hyperref` and use the command `\url{http:www-gap.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/HistTopics/Squaring_the_circle.html}` or (probably in other contexts) `\href{http:www-gap.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/HistTopics/Squaring_the_circle.html}{click on this link!}`. Most important: do not do `<\underline{http:www-gap.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/HistTopics/Squaring_the_circle.html}>`! I also wonder what all those `\ ` are meant to be doing in your `.tex` file.

Comment: Note that each `\bibitem` should be separated from the next one by a blank line. Remove the ``\\`` you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about the hyperref package? i.e.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

and then in your example

```
\bibitem{work1}...\ 
\bibitem{work9} J O'Connor i E F Robertson: 
Squaring the circle [en línia] 
\href{http:www-gap.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/HistTopics/Squaring_the_circle.html}\
```

for more details, have a look at e.g.

[How can I have colored and underlined links with hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref#26085)

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#.5Chyperref

Comment: The macro `\href` takes *two* mandatory arguments. Did you mean to write `\url{...}`?

Comment: correct, thank you. which option to chose depends  on what exactly the point of the question was ... not so clear to me