# Hyperlink color problem

Tags: hyperref

I read some answers on that questions, but it is still not working as expected.
The code says: link yellow, border green : the result is not the one I expect. If I change the colors, the result remains the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=yellow,
    linkbordercolor=green,
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1pt}}

\begin{document}

\href{%
    https://studio.code.org/s/course3/stage/2/puzzle/1}{%
    Labyrinthe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Whenever you say that code doesn't work as expected, it's usually a good idea to say exactly what you expect (even if it might be more or less obvious from the code).

Comment: The code says : link yellow, border green : the result is not the one expected, isn't it ;-)

Comment: It was a more general statement, it might not always be obvious from the code what the expected outcome would be (and I think there are cases where users have misconceptions about what code does, and thus have wrong expectations). That said, `urlcolor`, not `linkcolor`, but I can't give any good answer for the border.

Comment: I thaught `url` is for `http://...` and `link` for the friendly name. thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reset the border style AtBeginDocument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=yellow,
    urlbordercolor=green,
    pdfborder={1 1 1},
    }

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/S/W 1}}}
\begin{document}

\href{%
    https://studio.code.org/s/course3/stage/2/puzzle/1}{%
    Labyrinthe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}` if you want to underline.

Comment: Yellow and green? I can't make this work to see yellow and green. My border color never changes from the cyan border, nor the pink text with this code. Can you please collaborate? Thank you.

Comment: @KitOstrihon I must have missed your comment, and you are quite right, I mixed up linkcolor and urlcolor ...