# Costumize hyperref link exibition

Tags: hyperref

I have read a book on typography and have become interested in the way the author displays links (https://practicaltypography.com/how-to-use.html). He denotes cross-references with text written in small caps and external references with a small elevated red circle after the word-link. So I wondered if this could be done in LaTeX. So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I change the font style of text that goes inside \ref and \cref?
2. How can I change the big red box hyperref creates around a link to be a more discrete small circle or something like it?

In regard to number 1, I am able to do it for \cref using \crefformat, but I wonder if I can also have it for \ref in case I want to use the simple reference. As to number 2, I have read this question/answer ([How can I have colored and underlined links with hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref)), but it only shows how to change the box to underlining of dashed box.

Comment: The idea is interesting, and probably not very difficult to implement. However, one possible disadvantage of the external links is that you don't see where the link starts (i.e., which words are part of the link), because it looks the same as regular text. Therefore you need to click somewhere close to the circle to make sure you 'hit' the link, which seems to be less convenient than being able to see the full link with colored letters or with a box around the link.

Comment: You are right, that is what I have thought too. But that is why I think small caps are a good ideia. It will not be possible to dintinguish by sight if two words that are side by side and in small caps are one link or two separate links, but I do not think that is a major issue.

Comment: For changing the font of `\ref` I don't really understand the goal, the output of `\ref` is almost always just a number, which is not different in small caps, so what needs to be changed exactly?

Comment: you can easily suppress the red link border with `\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}`, but there is nothing in the PDF-format to add small circles, you will have to draw them e.g. with a degree symbol or with tikz. And they will be printed unless you add some ocg-layer.