# Make a link look more like a link

Tags: links, url

Is it possible to make the below url look more like a word/excel link?

Here is a small latex example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue
}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
Url: \url{https://stackexchange.com/}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I would like something, which looks like:

[image]

Any idea how to do that?

**Update**

I came by this solution, which is very close to what I want however it changes the font for the URL, which is not desired:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}
\makeatletter
\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl@@{
  \def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\color{blue}}
  \def\UrlLeft{\uline\bgroup}
  \def\UrlRight{\egroup}}
\def\ULurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{\ULurl@@{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\ULurl{\hyper@normalise\ULurl@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Url: \ULurl{https://stackexchange.com/}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I have colored and underlined links with hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref)

Comment: Yes, it is. However I can't get `linkbordercolor` to work and I'm also looking for a lighter blue, but not 'cyan'.

Comment: you can define your own colours using the `xcolor` package. do some research on the topic.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me, since it is references to a label in the document and I'm working with URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code:

- add a `%` symbol to remove the blank space before the url
- remove the `\ttfamily` font specifier to keep the same font or even use `\normalfont` to always format the url the same way

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}
\makeatletter
\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl@@{% <-- add this to remove space before url
%   \def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\color{blue}} <-- remove \ttfamily to keep the font
    \def\UrlFont{\color{blue}}%
    \def\UrlLeft{\uline\bgroup}%
    \def\UrlRight{\egroup}}
\def\ULurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{\ULurl@@{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\ULurl{\ULurl@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Url: \ULurl{https://stackexchange.com/}
\end{document}
```