# Colored underline

Tags: color, links, underline, url

I try to underline a url. I can't get it to work.
So now I will manually insert underline below my url.

How can a make the underline thinner and color it blue?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    urlbordercolor=blue,
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}
}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
Url: \uline{\url{https://stackexchange.com/}}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get with the above tex file:

[image]

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? I have added only `\usepackage{xcolor}` and `\textcolor{blue}{...}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    urlbordercolor=blue,
    pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}
}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
Url: \textcolor{blue}{\uline{\url{https://stackexchange.com/}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. This was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @User123456789 Ah :-) I am very happy to help you.