# Where is the definition (source code) of the command `\bibhyperref` and how to deal with similar problems in the future?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref

So, I'm trying to do some hacking related to the `\bibhyperref` command from the package `biblatex`. I want to modify this command because in line 552 of the file `biblatex.def` we would find

`\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{\bibhyperref{#1}}`

In my naive understanding, I think this means that basically all hyper references in the `biblatex` are handled by the command `\bibhyperref` through some other commands like `\printfield[bibhyperref]{...}` or `\printtext[bibhyperref]{...}` which may then be expanded as `\bibhyperref{...}`.

So next I try to find the definition (source code) of the command `\bibhyperref` so that I can hack it. I have searched the `tex` directory, but it seems that there exists no something which looks like a definition `\def\bibhyperref...` or `\newcommand\bibhyperref...` *et al*.

[image]

So I'm very confused about **where exactly (in which line of which file)** is this command defined? Or maybe my naive understanding of how hyper references works in `biblatex` is wrong and I should find some other commands to hack?

Also, is there a good strategy to do this in the future when I again need to find the definition of a command? Does there exist some kind of index or manual that record those kinds of information?

Comment: it is defined in biblatex.sty, but the definition method is rather special as the command is only active inside biblatex commands. I don't think that you should hack it. Better ask a question about your real problem so that someone can tell you a saner solution.

Comment: So, my actual need is to add underline to the `biblatex` hyper references following [this trick](https://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2005-March/014368.html). I understand that there exist [other, easier method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref) to realize this using the border of the hyperref.

Comment: Maybe there is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17840/250119  (texdef script) although I'm not sure if there's a good way for this case // alternatively check the source code documentation if it exists

Comment: But, 1) I find that in Mac Preview this underline reduces to an ugly box, so I assume that this underline is actually not machine and application-independent. 2) if the title is too long such that line break is implemented in the Table of Contents, then some extra underline where no text exists will show up.

Comment: I wouldn't use \uline to underline links. Links typically contain special chars and this is bound to break.  Imho only lualatex + lua-ul would be safe here. Setting pdfborder has some drawbacks, but it is easier to use and it doesn't print.

Comment: So you mean that lua-ul may be a better solution to implement the line break of the hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general grepping for `\def<commandname>`, `\let<commandname>`, `\newcommand<commandname>`, `\NewDocumentCommand<commandname>` (possibly without and with curly braces around `<commandname>` in the latter two cases) is a good start to find out about a command, but LaTeX is fairly flexible in how it allows commands to be defined, so it is impossible to give a finite list of search strings to identify all possible ways in which `<commandname>` could be defined.

For `\bibhyperref` specifically Ulrike already gave the right hint in the comments. That command is only defined in a `biblatex` context and has a different name outside of these contexts. This makes sure that the command cannot be used when it does not make sense and avoids name clashes with other packages.

One could argue that the command is defined in [ll. 11635-11636 of `biblatex.sty` (v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L11635-L11636)

```
\blx@regimcs{%
  \bibhyperref \bibhyperlink \bibhypertarget \ifhyperref}
```

Roughly speaking, `\blx@regimcs` makes sure that `\<commandname>` has the meaning of `\blx@imc@<commandname>` in `biblatex` contexts. So `bibhyperref`  is defined in terms of `\blx@imc@bibhyperref`.

`\blx@imc@bibhyperref` has two possible definitions depending on whether `hyperref` is loaded or not ([ll. 11588-11633 of `biblatex.sty` (v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L11588-L11633))

```
%  hyperref interface
\appto\blx@mkhyperref{%
  \protected\def\blx@imc@bibhyperref{%
    \@ifnextchar[%]
      {\blx@bibhyperref}
      {\blx@bibhyperref[\abx@field@entrykey]}}%
  \ifundef\hyper@natanchorstart
    {\long\def\blx@bibhyperref[#1]#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyperlink{cite.\the\c@refsection @#1}{\blx@sfrest
         #2%
       \blx@sfsave}\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhyperlink#1#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyperlink{cite.\the\c@refsection:#1}{\blx@sfrest
         #2%
       \blx@sfsave}\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhypertarget#1#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hypertarget{cite.\the\c@refsection:#1}{\blx@sfrest
         #2%
       \blx@sfsave}\blx@sfrest}}%
    {\long\def\blx@bibhyperref[#1]#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkstart{\the\c@refsection @#1}\blx@sfrest
       #2%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkend\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhyperlink#1#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkstart{\the\c@refsection:#1}\blx@sfrest
       #2%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkend\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhypertarget#1#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natanchorstart{\the\c@refsection:#1}\blx@sfrest
       #2%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natanchorend\blx@sfrest}}
  \let\blx@imc@ifhyperref\@firstoftwo
  \def\blx@sf{\spacefactor}%
  \def\blx@sfsave{%
    \blx@leavevmode
    \numgdef\blx@sf{\spacefactor}}%
  \def\blx@sfrest{%
    \ifhmode\spacefactor\blx@sf\relax\fi
    \gdef\blx@sf{\spacefactor}}}

\appto\blx@mknohyperref{%
  \protected\def\blx@imc@bibhyperref{\@ifnextchar[\blx@nohyperref\@firstofone}%
  \def\blx@nohyperref[#1]#2{#2}%
  \let\blx@imc@bibhyperlink\@secondoftwo
  \let\blx@imc@bibhypertarget\@secondoftwo
  \let\blx@imc@ifhyperref\@secondoftwo}
```

I agree with Ulrike that it is probably not a great idea to try and manipulate this command directly.

---

I don't think there is a silver bullet for these kind of questions. A big chunk of cases can probably be dealt with if you just look for `\def`, `\let`, `\newcommand` and friends. But it is always possible that a package uses complex constructions to define the macro you are interested in. A script like `latexdef` ([Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4327/35864)) can be helpful, but might not catch all the weird ways in which a package might define commands.

If you know which package defines your macro (e.g. because you can verify that with the documentation), you can narrow down your searches for that macro to files belonging to that package. So for `\bibhyperref`, where you can check that `biblatex` defines that command, you probably want to start grepping only in `tex/latex/biblatex` and not in style directories like `tex/latex/biblatex-chicago`.

From then on, there is no guaranteed way. I usually search for `\<commandname>` first and try to filter out which hits are uses of the macro and which look like they could be definitions. But sometimes it also helps to search for `<commandname>` without the leading backslash because there are several ways to define macros without giving the backslash in the definition. This can also turn up similarly named helper macros, which may or may not give you a sense where to look.

In the whole `biblatex` subtree there are only three hits for `\bibhyperref`. Two look like obvious uses of the macro. So the third one in `\blx@regimcs` is a candidate for the definition. To check if it is the right one, you'd need to check out the definition of `\blx@regimcs` and see what it does. From there you would find your way to `\blx@imc@bibhyperref`. But that may take a while and it definitely helps if you have some overall experience with the package you are dealing with.