# How can you add borders to internal links whilst having urls and citation numbers coloured?

Tags: hyperref, color, links, border, hyperlink

I'm using the hyperref package to colour my labels, citations and urls. Initially I had borders around the urls but I started used hypersetup because I wanted to remove the boxes and give the urls their typical blue colour. However, the problem comes now when I try to put borders around internal links (e.g. `Fig \ref{fig:1}, Section \ref{introduction}`) it can't manage to do it. I've tried writing `bordercolor = {1 0 0}` within hypersetup (commenting out linkcolor) to make the borders have a red colour but it didn't work at all. I've also tried passing `bordercolor = {1 0 0}` as a parameter within hypersetup (commenting out linkcolor) but nothing. Below you can see my current hyperrref and hypersetup configuration. I would appreciate your help.

Hyperref code:

```
\usepackage{hyperref} %Required to make links clickable and give them colour.

\hypersetup{ %Required to set up behaviour of the links in document
colorlinks=true, %Coulor links (i.e. no more boxes around links)
linkcolor=black, %Internal in-document link colour is made to be black
filecolor=magenta, %links to local files are set to magenta. 
urlcolor=blue, %Links to websites are set to blue.
pdftitle={My Doc}, %pdf title set to "My Doc"
pdfpagemode=UseNone, %No determined way to open the pdf.
citecolor=black,
}
```

Comment: don't show screenshots. Show a complete, small example that we can copy&paste to test your issues. That makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for telling me. I've changed now. I hope the code makes it clearer to test the issue.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/47927

Comment: Complete means something that starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document}